# How can I send an HTTP request using HTTP/2 over TLS? (Java 11 HttpClient)

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, http2, java-http-client

I am trying to create a proxy in a Java application that allows me to modify some aspects of HTTP requests.

To do this, I open a ServerSocket on port 8080, configure a Proxy in Mozilla Firefox on that port and, for each connection, execute the accept() method of ServerSocket in a separate thread. So far everything normal.

To send requests from the browser to the corresponding website, I use the HttpClient library included in Java 11. This is the piece of code where I use that library:

```java
private void obtainResponse(Socket socket, IHttpRequest req, String uri) {

        HttpClient client = null;
        if (req.isSSL()) {
            SSLContext sslContext = ((SecureConnectionHandler)connHandler).createSSLContext( req.getHost() );
            client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                    .priority(1)
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                    .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL)
                    .sslContext( sslContext )
                    .build();
        }
        else
            client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                    .priority(1)
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                    .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL)
                    .build();

        String protocolAndHost = ((req.isSSL()) ? "https://" : "http://") + req.getHost();

        if (uri == null)
            uri = protocolAndHost + req.getRequestedResource();
        else {
            if (uri.startsWith("/"))
                uri = protocolAndHost + uri;
            System.out.println("Aqui:" + uri);
        }

        HttpRequest.Builder preRequest=null;
        if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
            preRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()  // GET request!
                .uri(URI.create( uri ))
                .GET();
        }
        else if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            preRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()  // POST request!
            .uri(URI.create( uri ))
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(req.getBody()));
        }

        for (Header header : req.getHeaders()) {
            if (!header.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Host") &&
                !header.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Connection") &&
                !header.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Length") &&
                !header.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Upgrade") ) 
            {
                preRequest.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValues());
            }
        }
        HttpRequest request = preRequest.build();

        System.err.println("Request to: " + uri);

        HttpResponse<byte[]> response;
        try {
            response = client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofByteArray())
                             .join();   
        } catch (CompletionException ce) {
            System.err.println("Address " + uri + " is unreachable!");
            return ;
        }

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = response.headers();

        Optional<String> locationHeader = httpHeaders.firstValue("Location"); // When resource has been permanently moved

        if ( !locationHeader.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println("Moved permanently to " + locationHeader.get());
            obtainResponse( socket, req, locationHeader.get() );
        }
        else {
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = httpHeaders.map();

            String protocol = response.version().toString().replace("_", ".").replaceFirst("\\.", "/");

            int code = response.statusCode();

            String reasonPhrase = HttpStatus.getStatusText( code );

            var crlf = "\r\n";

            var responseString = protocol + " " + code + " " + reasonPhrase + crlf;

            for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
                responseString += key + ":";
                for (String valor : headers.get(key)) {
                    responseString += " " + valor;
                }
                responseString += crlf;
            }

            responseString += crlf; // espacio cabeceras y cuerpo

            writeResponse(socket, response.body(), responseString);
        }
    }


private void writeResponse(Socket socket, byte[] streamResponse, String responseHeaders) {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); 

            outputStream.write(responseHeaders.getBytes());
            outputStream.write(streamResponse);
            outputStream.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!socket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                }
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

**NOTE: IHttpRequest is a class created by me that contains all the information collected from the socket (target host, headers, body if it exists, etc.)**

So far I have successfully intercepted all requests directed to HTTP websites. However, I have problems with, for example, https://www.google.com/, which implements the HTTP / 2 protocol and uses TLS. When I run the Java application and access the previous Google page, instead of showing me the website it shows me the following in the browser (ignore the blanks between headers):

> HTTP/2 200 OK
>
> :status: 200
>
> alt-svc: quic = ":443"; ma = 2592000; v = "46,43,39"
>
> cache-control: private
>
> content-encoding: gzip
>
> content-length: 46058
>
> content-type: text/html; charset = UTF-8
>
> date: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 09:47:34 GMT
>
> Expires: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 09:47:34 GMT
>
> p3p: CP = "This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
>
> server: gws
>
> set-cookie: 1P_JAR = 2019-09-03-09; expires = Thu, 03-Oct-2019 09:47:34 GMT; 
>   path = /; domain = .google.com; SameSite = none NID = 188 = XOJkffugf5G8rxNLov_iqqxo-Cq5RCvhwJPNu9tvtzLesZ4q8CE0IDVt9VgCEHZsw-AV0EYaaL8D4d_2Qwb6jXCcss7RydfV9PqQFemN_Ezz0kUjyseDDbJXfrHpmqPR6GIQCnR7bjukfasxg883K9fjnhAaqz6IpUYxoguZx-vazWc; expires = Wed, 04-Mar-2020 09:47:34 GMT; path = /; domain = .google.com; HttpOnly CONSENT = WP.27dd1a; expires = Fri, 01-Jan-2038 00:00:00 GMT; path = /; domain = .google.com
>
> x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> x-xss-protection: 0

(↓↓BODY↓↓)

> ‹����� ÿÔ½ézâÈ² (ú¿Ÿ‚ ¢ örÁ²À or PªÚ ° çyÜÞ¾ © $ Æ.ÞåžG¸ßýwþ® »™ š ¶« »× ùöíê ¢ ¤T '' '' ™ 'ß¿ († l / Æj ¢ or õ ßñ7¡ “QOLªV ÞU ¢ üø> Tm' ûÄ´T [L ^] îd * I7Õ Ùê Rçšb ÷ EE i²š¡ / ÜP iÃé0cÉDWE! ËsCò I ™ ZªI_ ‰) ## ™ '* & gš: ¦½ÒŽêê¸oŒ ‚™» † 9 $ vFQmU¶5c´Rˆ (Š © ZÖï 1L§ Üì ¦ÚUMS5W² Û $ # K'¶êæí FOWWrniCÒS- ò + Ú¨ · Åòõ¶ „÷ ñÉ²á 1 • 'ÙÐ
>
> << And much more information in form of bytes >>

Do you see anything strange in my code? I know that HTTP / 2 compresses the headers in Frames, but I assumed that HTTPClient did it internally...

If you need more information let me know :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP/2 protocol is a binary protocol. What you are sending back to your browser is an HTTP/1.1 response (even if the protocol used by the HttpClient to obtain the response was HTTP/2).

Yet - your status line is `HTTP/2 200 OK` which your browser won't be able to understand. You need to send your response as a well formatted HTTP/1.1 response.
That includes filtering out headers whose keys start with ':' - like ':status' as these are HTTP/2 specific response headers. Also forwarding back all response headers without understanding them might simply not work: writing a full fledged  HTTP Proxy is hard.

Comment: So ... what would you do? Any library to help me solve this problem? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have made it work by adding the following line in the obtainResponse method:

protocol = protocol.replace ("HTTP/2", "HTTP/1.1");

What problems arise from adding this line?

Comment: That's just what I was saying. You're sending back an HTTP/1.1 response to your browser. The status line must therefore begin with "HTTP/1.1 ".

Comment: And what inconveniences exist when doing this? Thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're asking what inconvenience there are in not following the specification of the HTTP protocol?

Comment: No, I just want to know if there is any problem with not really using HTTP/2 and continuing with HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Trying to use HTTP/2 would force you to implement the HTTP/2 protocol (server side) and that's much more difficult than implementing HTTP/1.1. I assume you could use a library that supports server side HTTP/2 to do that if you wanted to. But in any case you can't send an HTTP/2 response to an HTTP/1.1 request. That doesn't make sense: it's not the same protocol. Unless the HTTP/1.1 request is an upgrade request but in that case you would still need to implement HTTP/2.